# how to model a map of a collection of entities with JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, model

I'm trying to model an inbox entity with jpa...

My idea is that the inbox is a map of a set of messages, the map shall be indexed from the 'topic' of conversation, the topic is a column of the message entity which include a concatenation of the sender+receiver names ALWAYS IN ALPHABETICAL ORDER... this way both parties in a conversation will always address to same topic

```
@Table(name = "chat_box")
@Entity(name = "ChatBox")
public class ChatBox {

   @NotNull
   @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, targetEntity = ChatMessage.class)
   @MapKeyColumn(name = "address_type")
   @MapKey(name = "sender")
   private final Map<@NonNull String, @NonNull Set<@NonNull ChatMessage>> messageList = new HashMap<>();
}


@Table(name = "chat_message",
        uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(name = "unique_conversation", columnNames = {"conversation"})},
        indexes = {@Index(name = "index_conversation", unique = true, columnList = "conversation")}
)
@Entity(name = "ChatMessage")
public class ChatMessage extends BasicEntity {

   @NotBlank(message = "O campo 'remetente' não pode estar em branco")
   @Size(min = 1, max = 63, message = "O campo 'remetente' deve ter entre ${min} e ${max} carácteres, valor informado; '${validatedValue}'")
   @Column(name = "sender", unique = false, nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = false, length = 63)
   private String sender;

   @NotBlank(message = "O campo 'destinatario' não pode estar em branco")
   @Size(min = 1, max = 63, message = "O campo 'destinatario' deve ter entre ${min} e ${max} carácteres, valor informado; '${validatedValue}'")
   @Column(name = "receiver", unique = false, nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = false, length = 63)
   private String receiver;

   @NotBlank(message = "O campo 'mensagem' não pode estar em branco")
   @Size(min = 1, max = 511, message = "O campo 'mensagem' deve ter entre ${min} e ${max} carácteres, valor informado; '${validatedValue}'")
   @Column(name = "message", unique = false, nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = false, length = 511)
   private String message;

   @Column(name = "_read", unique = true, nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)
   private boolean read;

   @Column(name = "conversation", unique = true, nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = false, length = 127)
   public String getConversation() {
      return receiver.toLowerCase().compareTo(sender.toLowerCase()) < 1 ? String.format("%s_%s", receiver, sender) : String.format("%s_%s", sender, receiver);
   }

}
```

how shall i annotate the map property for it to work as intended??
is it a good aproach? should i create another entity which is a set o chatmessage then just create a map of this entity ?

all help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you want to model this with 2 tables, you will have introduce an intermediate layer e.g. a domain model layer, because JPA can not model a `Map<?, Collection<?>>`. In your entity model, you'd use a model similar to the following:

```java
@Entity(name = "ChatBox")
public class ChatBox {

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
   @JoinColumn(name = "sender", referencedColumnName = "owner")
   private final Set<@NonNull ChatMessage> messages = new HashSet<>();
}


@Entity(name = "ChatMessage")
public class ChatMessage extends BasicEntity {

   @Column(name = "address_type", unique = false, nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = false, length = 63)
   private String topic;

   @Column(name = "sender", unique = false, nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = false, length = 63)
   private String sender;

   @Column(name = "receiver", unique = false, nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = false, length = 63)
   private String receiver;

   @Column(name = "message", unique = false, nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = false, length = 511)
   private String message;

   @Column(name = "_read", unique = true, nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)
   private boolean read;

}
```

I think this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(ChatBox.class)
public interface ChatBoxDto {
    @IdMapping
    Long getId();
    @MappingIndex("topic")
    Map<String, Set<ChatMessageDto>> getMessages();

    @EntityView(ChatMessage.class)
    interface ChatMessageDto {
        @IdMapping
        Long getId();
        String getSender();
        String getReceiver();
        String getMessage();
        boolean isRead();
    }
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`ChatBoxDto a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, ChatBoxDto.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
Page<ChatBoxDto> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

The best part is, it will only fetch the state that is actually necessary!